# Version control repository for user data

Tags: mysql, version-control, repository

What tools or any guides on how to model my mysql schema to store user content under version control? Similar to a svn repository but instead of code i need to version all user objects. Like what photos did the user have 2 yrs ago on this date. What settings did he have, etc. Yes i can store backup copies in tables but the problem is there are hundreds and hundreds of tables involved due to different kinds of objects. And i will be taking shanpshots each day for now and plan to implement it with each edit later. So basically I am wondering how svn repository store content in the databse or how does windows store restore points in some database so i can mimic that model for user data. Only requirement for me is i need to use mysql for the main database. the way i see it is:

Active data and Historical data. Active data has current copy. Historical data is indexed by date/time. But still to maintain hundreds of table data for each user each day that mean 365 x number of users x number of table rows i need to version. i dont know if moeling it in mysql in 3NF is the best way to go?

Comment: seems like you need to refactor the scheme of the db first. Can you show us the current scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a timpstamp field along with every database entry. Then do lazy deletion instead of deleting the data, i.e. have a "deleted" field which again can store a timestamp of the deletion. These combined will allow you to do historical queries.

When you get to implementing this from historic snapshots, you can estimate a timestamp based on the first/last snapshot you see an entry in and ammend the database entries accordingly.

Comment: But how to control the tables then? Take your profile detail for example. it has say 50 fields across 10 tables. i take shapshot 365 day and i have 10 million users. so after 1 year i will have 3 billion and 650 million rows per table?

Comment: You only store a new row when a change occurs. Typically far less than once a day.

Answer (score 0):

Version control is a non-trivial problem.  It has been solved in numerous ways but redoing it yourself correctly is far from trivial.  [Eric Sink](http://www.ericsink.com/) writes a very good blog on the development of his own version control software which gives some little idea of the complexity

Your particular problem will be volume of data, as many of your files will be binary which are not stored as efficiently by VC systems since they are designed primarily to deal with text.  Very quickly unless you have a very good diff engine you will end up with too much data to be work with.

My suggestion would be to concentrate on interfacing your software with something where someone has already done the hard work such as Subversion, Git, Mercurial or one of the other excellent source control tools available.  You could use those as your repository to store and version all the files and build your software ontop to make sense of it all.

To build an efficient version control system you need to really know what your doing, why not reuse what the experts have created.

If you are still gung ho on doing it yourself you could do worse than [Eric Sinks Source Control How-To](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html)